# What’s the average length of chords at a given angle in a rectangle?

Tags: geometry, definite-integrals, rectangles

Articles are published on average length of chords on circles, squares, rectangles etc..like [1] where they considered either random chords or chords at all angles in a regular geometry, but I could not find a result for average length of chords which are at a prescribed angle in a rectangle, refer the figure for a clear idea. How would you derive an expression for that?

[image: chords in a rectangle]

[1] Kuchel, P. W., & Vaughan, R. J. (1981). Average lengths of chords in a square. Mathematics Magazine, 54(5), 261-269.

Comment: If you understand how it is done for a prescribed angle in a square, the same method can be used in a rectangle as well, though the formula at the end will not be exactly the same.

Comment: You need to specify the distribution of chords before this is answerable. Do you 1) pick a line $y = ax+b$ which intersects the rectangle while $a$ is given and $b$ is uniformly distributed. 2) pick a point $(x_0,y_0)$ uniformly from the rectangle and consider line of the form $y = y_0 + a(x - x_0)$ with $a$ fixed.
3) pick a point $(x_1,y_1)$ uniformly on the boundary of the rectangle and consider lines of the form $y = y_1 + a(x-x_1)$.

Comment: It appears that the cited article (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267058362_Average_Lengths_of_Chords_in_a_Square#fullTextFileContent) never answers this question (average length of a chord in a field of lines at a given angle) even for a square. Moreover, the answer it gives for a field of lines at random angle appears to be incorrect.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I edited the question based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any shape, the area is obtained as the height times the average horizonal chord length.

Hence for a *rotated* rectangle, the average horizontal chord length is

$$\frac{WH}{|H\cos\theta|+|W\sin\theta|}.$$
Note that the average value on $\theta$ is $$\frac{2WH}\pi\left|\text{artanh}\left(\frac HD\right)-\text{artanh}\left(\frac WD\right)\right|$$ where $D$ is the diagonal and this is the average chord length regardless the orientation.

---

[image]

---

For a circle,

$$\frac{\pi r^2}{2r}.$$

For an ellipse,

$$\frac{2\pi ab}{\sqrt{a^2\cos^2\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta}}.$$

For an arbitrary triangle,

$$\frac{\begin{vmatrix}x_1-x_0&y_2-y_0 \\ x_2-x_0&y_2-y_1\end{vmatrix}}{2(\max(y_0,y_1,y_2)-\min(y_0,y_1,y_2))}.$$

If you rotate it, the area remains the same and the ordinates are replaced as

$$y_k\leftrightarrow y_k\cos\theta+x_k\sin\theta.$$

Comment: Excellent proof with interesting extensions.

Answer (score 3):

We can assume, without loss of generality, that the rectangle is always with its larger side (its length) presented verticaly, along the $y$ axis, its smaller side, its width, being horizontal. Let us call their resp. measures $L$ and $W$ (see Fig. 1 on the left).

When the line with equation $y=ax+b$ for fixed

$$a = \tan \alpha \ \ (\text{we can assume WLOG that } \ \ 0 < \alpha < \pi/2) \tag{1}$$

and variable $b$ sweeps the rectangle, the length of its "intercepts" (synonym of "chords") as a function of $b$ is a trapezoid-shaped function as represented on the right of the figure.

[image]

*Fig. 1 : The case where $a=\tan \alpha < \tfrac{L}{W}$ (the other case has a very similar aspect).*

The average intercept length is the mean value of this function.

Instead of using an integral computation, it's worth using a geometric argument.

With the notations introduced in the figure (in particular with $h:=W\sqrt{1+a^2}$) :

- During the "plateau" phase, which has a "weight" $\color{red}{L-aW}$, the average is plainly $h$.
- During the ascending and descending phases, the average intercept length is $h/2$. The total "weight" of these phases is $\color{red}{2aW}$.

Now, take the barycenter to get :

$$\text{ave. intercept length} \ = \ \dfrac{\color{red}{(L-aW)}h+\color{red}{(2aW)} h/2}{\color{red}{(L-aW)+(2aW)}}=\dfrac{Lh}{L+aW}=\dfrac{LW\sqrt{1+a^2}}{L+aW}$$

which can be written (I am indebted to @David K who has pointed it to me)

$$\text{ave. intercept length} \ = \ \dfrac{LW / \cos\alpha}{L+W\tan\alpha}=\dfrac{LW}{L\cos\alpha+W\sin\alpha}.$$

Remarks :

1) Here is an [active link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267058362_Average_Lengths_of_Chords_in_a_Square#fullTextFileContent) for the first reference given by the OP.

2) For more, see the properties of the so-called ["support function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_function) of a convex set.

Comment: The question does not say what formula was found for the square, but it should be equivalent to the formula shown in this answer when $L = W$ and $0 \leq \alpha \leq \frac\pi4.$

Comment: @David K  Very valuable remark(s) !  Thank you  !

Comment: I just found an online version of the article (see added Remark). Its formulas encompass the general case (random orientation). But I must have a closer look.

Comment: My first remark had an error at the end (regarding interchanging sine and cosine). Since the correct part of the comment is now in the answer, I have deleted the comment.